# How to compile kotlin with incremental compilation and cache from command line?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to compile kotlin with incremental compilation and cache, and ideally without building the jar? To make it faster.

Example:

I have two kotlin files in the `play` folder

user.kt

```
data class User(val name: String)
```

play.kt

```
fun main() {
  val user = User("Jim")
  println("Hello ${user.name}")
}
```

The usual way to compile and run is with this command:

```
kotlinc . -include-runtime -d play.jar && java -jar play.jar
```

Is there a way to speed it up? By using incremental compilation and cache, avoiding building jar and avoiding merging runtime? How the compile&run command would look like?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the codebase, but based on the readme the language server does this, so you might have a look at that: https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server

Comment: @somethingsomething a very interesting idea, thanks! :)